# Proving the piecewise function is bijective

Tags: functions

Prove that the function $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \cup \{{0}\}$ defined by

$$f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             2x  & x \geq 0 \\
             \\ -2x-1& x<0 \\
             \\ 
             \end{array}
   \right.$$
is bijective.

I don't have any familiarity with piecewise functions when dealing with bijective proofs yet. I'm assuming I have to show the bijection for two separate cases? Like for injective assume $f(x)=f(y)$ for some and arrive at $x=y$ with both cases? Would it be possible to find an inverse which would imply its bijective also?

Comment: Both are valid proof methods, assuming that 'two separates cases' would mean proving both injectivity and surjectivity. And yes, it's possible to explicity write a bijection for $f$.

Comment: Be careful proving injectivity on both 'branches' of the function. The function $$f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}: x\mapsto \begin{cases}x+2 & x \leq 0 \\ x & x > 0\end{cases}$$ is injective on $(-\infty,0]$ and injective on $(0,+\infty)$, but it is not injective on $\Bbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

Inverse: $g:\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\to\mathbb{Z}$

$$g(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             \frac{x}{2}  & x \text{ is even} \\
             \\ -\frac{x+1}{2}& x\text{ is odd} \\
             \end{array}
   \right.$$